# Blazor, Is this Singleton abuse? (Sharing iframe values)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

First of all, let me explain why I think I need a singleton. I'm integrating several Hosted Checkout payment processors into my Blazor Server application. All of them work as follows;

- `Index.razor` has an Iframe that displays a payment processors url.
- When the customer completes the payment the iframe redirects back to a url specified by my application, `PaymentComplete.razor`.

  - `PaymentComplete.razor` uses a **scoped service** `HostedCheckoutService` to raise an event to `Index.razor` containing the payment response.

**This is where the problem comes in**. `PaymentComplete.razor` is hosted inside an **iframe** therefore is treated with a separate scope. Any property changes or events raised by `HostedCheckoutService` from within `PaymentComplete.razor` wont be `Index.razor`. This makes it (nearly?) impossible to merge information from within the iframe to the scope of `Index.razor`.

What obviously solves this issue is registering `HostedCheckoutService` as a **singleton**. Now the problem is that when one client raises an event from `PaymentComplete.razor`, **all** clients will have to handle it.

To solve this I created an `IndexBase` with a unique property named `EventTargetId`. When the iframe payment is completed, the return url to `PaymentComplete.razor` will contain the `EventTargetId` in the query string.

**IndexBase.cs**

```
<iframe style="width:100%;height:50vh" src="@HostedCheckoutFrameSrc " frameborder="0" ></iframe> 


public class IndexBase : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    [Inject] NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
    [Inject] HostedCheckoutService HostedCheckoutService { get; set; }
    [Inject] PaymentApi PaymentApi { get; set; }

    public string HostedCheckoutFrameSrc { get; set; }
    public string EventTargetId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        HostedCheckoutService.OnPaymentComplete += PaymentComplete;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        HostedCheckoutService.OnPaymentComplete -= PaymentComplete;
    }

    private void PaymentComplete(string eventTargetId, string paymentJson)
    {
        // Hosted checkout iframe has returned a successfull payment.
        // Do something, send order, notification, ect.
    }

    public async Task InitializePayment()
    {
        string returnUrl = NavigationManager.BaseUri + $"/PaymentComplete?eventTargetId={EventTargetId}";
        InitializePaymentResponse response = await PaymentApi.CreatePaymentRequest(returnUrl);
        // Set iframe src property to third party payment providers url.
        // When customer completes third party payment url, the iframe redirects to PaymentComplete.razor (returnUrl).
        HostedCheckoutFrameSrc = PaymentApi.baseUrl + response.PaymentId;
    }
}
```

**PaymentComplete.razor (redirected from third party url, hosted inside iframe)**

This page will grab the `EventTargetId` from the query string and raise an event on our singleton service.

```
[Inject] NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
[Inject] PostFormService PostFormService { get; set; }
[Inject] HostedCheckoutService HostedCheckoutService { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // We face double render problem, but Form values will be null on secord render anyways.
    if (PostFormService.Form != null)
    {
        NavigationManager.TryGetQueryString<string>("eventTargetId", out string eventTargetId);
        string paymentJson = PostFormService.Form?["PaymentResponse"];
        HostedCheckoutService.PaymentCompleted(eventTargetId, paymentJson);
    }
}
```

In my singleton `HostedCheckoutService`, I filter out any subscribers using the `EventTargetId`.

```
public class HostedCheckoutService 
{
    public event Action<string, string> OnPaymentComplete;

    public void PaymentCompleted(string eventTargetId, string paymentJson)
    {
        // Instead of raising the event for every instance attached to this action
        // only raise the event for the specified target.
        var instance = OnPaymentComplete.GetInvocationList()
                            .Where(d => d.Target is IndexBase && ((IndexBase)d.Target).EventTargetId == eventTargetId)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
        instance?.DynamicInvoke(eventTargetId, paymentJson);
    }
}
```

**Finally, the question! Does this seem like an unacceptable use of singleton events or does anyone have a better approach?** Even though every client wont be handling the event, a call to `GetInvocationList()` would still contain a list of every subscribed class.

**Note:** Each event subscriber would not actually be a full `IndexBase` class. It would be a simple payment component (I simplified this example).

Comment: How many simultaneoius subscribers to `OnPaymentComplete` would you anticipate?  The  `.Where` after `.GetInvocationList` could potentially be a performance problem.

Comment: @KirkWoll Not too many I would say maybe 100 max. But the dream is to get to thousands ha! `OnPaymentComplete ` will only be subscribed to during the final checkout page, and it will timeout. Any ideas to make it more lightweight?

Comment: At that volume, what you have would work, and while I think it's safe from prying eyes, the `paymentJson` makes me a bit nervous.

Comment: But better would be to use SignalR (since you're server side, you're obviously already using it under the hood).  You can create a custom group (probably involving your event id) and that way the communication would only happen between hosting page and its iframe.  See this [chat example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) by Microsoft, and imagine the members of the chat "room" are just the two parties involved in this communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main concern would be scaling on calling all the registered methods on the event.

As I don't know what else `HostedCheckoutService` does, what about having a singleton `PaymentTransactionService` that contains a simple collection of Guids against Actions - and probably registration times to operate a timeout system .  Index calls a `Register` method on `PaymentTransactionService` to register it's Guid and it's Action.  - and obviously a `ReRegister` method when it `Disposes`.  `PaymentComplete` calls a `TransactionComplete` method on `PaymentTransactionService`.  It checks it's list and executes the registered action if there is one - and logs an error if there isn't.  You can use each `PaymentComplete` call to also kick off a managment routine that checks timeouts and removed expired registrations.

Comment: I like the idea of removing `GetInvocationList`. `HostedCheckoutService` is just the code you see posted in the question, nothing additional. It's job is to connect the action to the Guid like you described. The difference is instead of using a `Register` method you recommended, it uses `GetInvocationList` to find the subscriber with the Guid. I think the only downside of your approach would be appropriately disposing of the elements in the collection of Guids, since that is no longer automatically determined by `GetInvocationList`. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: If you implement dispose correctly in the components then everything should be ok.  If you implement a timeout and check all entries against their timeout every time you call the get that will clear out any expired entries.  I've used a similar approach for transaction logging.  Post a comment here if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you, I took your suggestions and it seems to work good. The only difference is I used a `System.Timers.Timer` to raise a timeout/timeout warning event. So I end up having three events attached to the Guid, `OnPaymentComplete`, `OnTimeout`, `OnTimeoutWarning`.